# Cancelling sending information upon clicking on "Cancel" from VSTO Add in

Tags: c#, wpf, http-post, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a custom add in for Outlook, there is a ribbon and it has a button "Send Info", when i click it, it opens a WPF form which has a save and cancel buttons, when the save is clicked it grabs a list of phone numbers and sends it via Http post to an application that saved them. The problem is that, if the user click on "Cancel", it should cancel the whole process at any point.. What is happening is that when you click Save, it will send whatever is there and if cancel is clicked, it would still save some... Is there a way to cancel the whole process by clicking on the cancel button on the form?.

I just need some guidance as to how others have done this or were able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it helps:

```
private Thread td;

void Save()
{
    //initialize the thread here
    //...
    td.Start();
    //...
}

void Cancel()
{
    if (td != null && td.IsAlive)
    {
        //warning canceling
        //...
        td.Abort();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try using CancellationTokenSource(requeirs .net4.5) also. Google it.@ergwin